# How can i set the routing perspective in HERE maps?

Tags: android, here-api

I am using the android premium SDK to calculate a route and then use the turn by turn navigation.

I am using following method to start the navigation:

```
m_navigationManager.startNavigation(route);
```

Everthying works fine, i see the location marker and the map follows automatically the current position.

Now i added a gesture Listener so that a user of my android app can zoom in and zoom out on the map. But then i loose the perspective and the current location marker will not be followed anymore.

How can i programatically force the perspective back to follow the current location marker?
How can i change in turn by turn navigation mode the perspective anyway?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set `NavigationManager.setMapUpdateMode(...)` to `NavigationManager.MapUpdateMode.ROADVIEW` before starting the navigation.